# Making SQL queries with C# in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, connection-string, localdb

I wanted to make a controller in an ASP.NET project that executes a query to a local db (I am using SQL Server From Visual Studio).
The code is the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
public class EsempiController : ApiController
{
    [Route ("api/Esempi/Ruoli")]
    [HttpGet]
    public void GetRuoli()
    {
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=True;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Pippo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQLServer Local DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB\TestDB.mdf;Connect Timeout=30;TrustServerCertificate = False";
        string query = "SELECT Ruoli FROM [dbo].Ruoli ";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            connection.Open();
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to execute the code and searching on: *localhost:44363/api/Esempi/Ruoli* I get the following error:
***System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException**: 'An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\Pippo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQLServer Local DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB\TestDB.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.'*

This error is showed when the line *connection.Open()* is executed.

I have already seen other similar problems here but I can't figure it out...
Thanks for the help

PS: I'm using VS 2019 if this can help to undestand.

Comment: Change `Data Source` to `.\SQLEXPRESS`.

Comment: "A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share". We can rule out the last one just by looking at the path. What have you done to try and rule out either of the other causes? Obviously, we can't see your environment.

Comment: try this:
string connectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Pippo\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SQLServer Local DB\\Instances\\MSSQLLocalDB\\TestDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

Comment: Unfortunately, about the first and third comments, nothing change with these two solutions.
About the second comment: 
What I did was to create a sql db with only one Table called [dbo].Ruoli (as u can see in the previous code). Then I modified the controller with that code. Maybe I've missed something.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this site](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) to help you configure you connection string.

An connection string example I am using to do the same thing is:
"Server= localhost; Database= [TABLE_NAME]; Integrated Security=True;"